# How can Hilt be used effectively in multi-module apps following CLEAN architecture principles?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, solid-principles, clean-architecture, dagger-hilt

I am building an Android app following the Clean Architecture Principles. Here is what I've got:

**app module**:

- Contains all the Android dependencies.
- Uses MVVM with ViewModel from the arch components.
- ViewModels only communicate with UseCases, which are constructor injected.

**usecase module**:

- Contains all of the use cases.
- Use cases only communicate with Repositories, which are constructor injected.

**repository module**:

- Contains all of the repositories.
- Repositories communicate with web services or database etc.
- I have a Retrofit interface defined in this layer, which the repository takes in it's constructor.

**data module**:

- Contains all the data models

I am trying to use Hilt for dependency injection in the app. I don't want to expose Retrofit, OkHttp etc to the app module because I don't want developers to be able to put network code in the wrong module. Remember, the app module uses ViewModel which can ONLY talk to use cases.

How do I set this up? I tried putting dagger modules in each of these modules to define injection, then in the main **app module** I included the module from usecase:

```kotlin
@Module(includes = [UseCaseModule::class])
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AppModule
```

but this does not work as it starts to complain about not being able to find transitive dependencies in the other modules that I want to keep hidden.

Comment: do you find any solution.

Comment: I have same problem

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, **Hilt** uses a monolithic approach currently. This means that your `app` module will have access to **ALL** your modules.

> I don't want to expose Retrofit, OkHttp etc. to the app module because I don't want developers to be able to put network code in the wrong module.

No, you don't have to include your network-related classes in the `app` module. Rather, in the `data` module.

But bear in mind that the `app` module will still indirectly have access to Retrofit by implementing the `data` module for Hilt to work.
You can check out this [post](https://princessdharmy.medium.com/migrating-dagger2-to-hilt-in-a-multi-module-app-using-clean-architecture-a64a96803304).

Comment: So, if ```app``` module isn't depend 'data', Hilt will not working?

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR:** Use Hilt version 2.40+ which allows working with transitive dependencies

---

Since Hilt version 2.37 there's an gradle flag `enableAggregatingTask` which
allows Hilt to collect transitive dependencies. The flag is enabled by default in version 2.40 and newer.

When you have your gradle modules as `:app -> :usecase -> :repository -> :retrofit (external)` and assuming you use `implementation` in your gradle scripts, your `Retrofit` instance can still be provided and injected in `:repository` module, but it won't leak into other modules.

So in case you want to encapsulate your `Retrofit` in your repository module, you may create

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {

  @Provides
  fun provideRetrofit(retrofitBuilder: Retrofit.Builder): YourApi = retrofitBuilder.create<YourApi>()

}
```

You don't need to manually include your `RepositoryModule` in `:app` as this is done by Hilt and the `@InstallIn` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same approach with multi-module, but a bit more extense than yours and it works (app, core, navigation, api, data, domain, presentation, coreAndroidTest).

For the **AppModule**, you don't need to specify that includes **UseCaseModule**, just make sure you add @InstallIn ApplicationComponent:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideContext(app: Application): Context = app.applicationContext

    @Provides
    fun provideResources(app: Application): Resources = app.resources
}
```

The same way when you define your **UseCaseModule** in a different module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
class DomainModule {
// Your @Provides
}
```

Comment: not getting you

Comment: Could you please help me with this issue @Fernando Prieto Moyano?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73089553/android-kotlin-hilt-multi-module-app-cannot-access-application-class-from