# Hilt in non-android module clean architecture setup

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, android-module

I have a multi modular android app setup which consists of a Data, Domain and Presentation module. The Domain module is java-only. I know it's possible to support hilt in non-android modules by adding:

Domain `build.gradle`

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-core:$hilt_version"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

The domain module provides implementations of UseCase classes that should be injected in the ViewModels which live in the Presentation (app)module.

Domain Module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
//   @InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object UseCaseModule {

    @Provides
    //    @ViewModelScoped
    fun provideGetMovieDetailsUseCase(
        movieRepository: MovieRepository
    ): GetMovieDetailsUseCase {
        return GetMovieDetailsUseCaseImpl(movieRepository)
    }
}
```

Presentation Module:

```
@HiltViewModel
class MovieDetailViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getMovieDetailsUseCase: GetMovieDetailsUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    ...
}
```

Because of the nature of the java-only module, I can't use the `@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)` annotation. Instead I have to install the dependency in the `SingletonComponent::class`. Which is also done in an awnser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669924/how-can-hilt-be-used-effectively-in-multi-module-apps-following-clean-architectu)

**My Question**

Is this approach 'best practice'? Or is it better to make the library an Android library so that I can scope the dependency to the ViewModel? I would prefer to keep it a java-only library.

Comment: @ADM The comment is misleading. The module is marked as a SingletonComponent not the type it provides.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A common practice I'm aware of is moving dependency configuration for all modules to the `app` module (since the use of `Hilt` is at the framework level). You can then use the java inject library to inject dependencies in the pure java libraries (e.g domain layer).

So in your `app` `build.gradle` file, you'll have:

```
// hilt dependency
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha"
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha02'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha02'
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"
```

and in your `domain` `build.gradle` file, you'll have:

```
implementation "javax.inject:javax.inject:$javaInjectVersion"
```

In summary, the file where you "wire up" the domain module dependencies should be moved to the `app` module.

[Here's a project](https://github.com/TobiAlbert/4Cast) that demonstrates the idea.

Comment: ahh yes thank you, all i had to do was to move the UseCaseModule to my presentation layer. :)

Comment: if you want to use hilt in the underlying modules, you can do this with 'com.google.dagger:hilt-core'

Answer (score -1):

This is my hit on the clean architecture and hilt

- **data** is a java-only module with datasource interfaces, repository interfaces and models
  [image: data]
- **domain** is a java-only module with usecase interfaces and entities
  [image]
- **framework** is an android module where the actual implementations of datasources, repositories and usecases are found. This is the same module where the Hilt Modules are declared
  [image: framework]
- **app** is the app module with domain and framework as dependencies